# How to get cross domain request's response in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, request, cross-domain, dynamic-script-loading

I am making a cross domain request in javascript by dynamically adding a script and setting its src attribute to the domain that I need to make request to.
For reference: http://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/feb13/

Script code:

```
var script_id = null;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', crossDomainURL);
script.setAttribute('id', 'script_id');

script_id = document.getElementById('script_id');
if (script_id) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(script_id);
}
```

Now, I need to parse the Response of this request.  I have checked the Raw Response from fiddler. The data is there, but it's not in the dom. It starts like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    if (top == self || parent != top || document.location.hostname != document.domain) 
    {  
        top.location.replace("http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/?gringotts_redir");}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"**... then the rest
```

The page source shows the javascript embedded by me, how do I parse the data that's generated from that code.

Comment: can you provide the location that you're requesting so I can see the complete response

Answer (score 1):

The way this is generally done is to have the script response consist of a function call to a function already present on the page.  The browser will not let your code "see" the contents of the imported script, however, for security reasons. The browser *will* run the script, however, so long as it's valid JavaScript code. In your case, the response is **not** valid JavaScript code. There can't be a `<script>` tag or any HTML markup — it must be pure JavaScript code, just like the contents of any other file imported with a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

What your asking for is known as JSONP or "JSON with padding".

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP for more info.